# You studied for this exam right?

Tags: mathematics

Complete the exam, include your reasoning:

1. 2 + 2 = 4
2. 2 + 3 = 5
3. 2 + 4 = 6
4. 9 + 2 = 11
5. 5 + 5 = 25
6. 6 + 8 = 48
7. 7 + 5 = __
8. 1 + 7 = __
9. 3 + 9 = __

(In the event someone wants to try to reason out my original logic I am adding a bonus page to give more examples.)

1. 2 + 3 = 6
2. 9 + 5 = 14
3. 6 + 9 = 15
4. 9 + 2 = 11
5. 2 + 3 = 6
6. 7 + 7 = 49
7. 7 + 9 = __
8. 4 + 9 = __
9. 4 + 8 = __

(giving a second bonus round this time 2x as long.)

1. 8 + 3 = 24
2. 8 + 9 = 17
3. 7 + 1 = 8
4. 7 + 1 = 8
5. 7 + 9 = 63
6. 5 + 8 = 40
7. 5 + 7 = 35
8. 6 + 1 = 7
9. 6 + 5 = 11
10. 7 + 5 = 12
11. 9 + 9 = 81
12. 8 + 9 = 72
13. 9 + 2 = 18
14. 6 + 9 = 15
15. 4 + 9 = 13
16. 5 + 6 = 11
17. 4 + 3 = 12
18. 4 + 3 = __
19. 5 + 6 = __
20. 6 + 9 = __

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Sometimes is better to add a story rather than just putting the puzzle and nothing else.  eg http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Are you sure about 6th one.

Comment: Yes. I confirmed 6 using a calculator now.

Comment: Consider adding another example as your question has many answers that are not your expected one.

Comment: I have done as you suggest. I actually find the unexpected solutions more curious and interesting than the expected ones.

Comment: 2+3 = 6 and 5 ?

Comment: @Jamal Actually 1. 2+3 = 6 and 2. 2+3 = 5

Comment: Just a comment on the downvotes as it can be disheartening for new users.  The general expectation is there is enough information in the puzzle to give a unique answer.  It seems once the bonus rounds were added there should be plenty of info now.

Comment: I honestly had no idea at the onset that the first set or even the second set would have so many coincidental solutions. Though I found it interesting that there was the potential for such coincidences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so, new rule :

> n°1 is a multiplication, then, it's 3 multiplication, 3 addition, 3 multiplications, ... ad infinitum (kind of like a sine wave)

So, page 1

> 35 , 8 , 12

Page 2

> 63, 13, 12

Page 3

> 12, 30, 15

Comment: This is by far the simplest way to go about it, and I really hope that OP does not go back and churn out yet another long list that suddenly proves this theory wrong.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Though put a different way than I had in my head.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the rule

> If there's a "2" in the equation, then add, else multiply

works as well, so

> 35, 7, 27 respectively is a possible answer

But there is quite a lot of other possible answers

Edit to propose a solution that works for both pages :

> add for questions 2,3 and 4 ... multiply for everything else . Somehow, the two pages seem to follow the exact same index based list of operations (is there a number sequence starting with 2,3,4 (or 1,5,6) ?)

so

> 63, 36, 32

Comment: Wow. That is again an interesting and unexpected answer. I'm wondering if I should have included more cases but the fact that so totally different valid solutions are coming out seems more interesting than finding if someone could figure out the esoteric rule I made for creating questions.

Comment: Hrm. May have been worth going beyond 9 in the second sequence. Not a bad solution however.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are:

> $35$, $7$, $27$ respectively.

Because,

> All the given data points satisfy the formula: $$x+y:=(x+y)+\left|\text{sgn}(xy-2x-2y+4)\right|((x-1)(y-1)-1).$$
> So using this formula we can find the required values. Note that here $\text{sgn}(x)$ denotes the [Signum Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Evidence:

> [image]

Comment: The fact that this solution works is rather curious and impressive. Would have been interesting to see if you could pull off a similar one if I had included more examples in accordance with my own rules.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a solution that works with the bonus page.

> Multiply if the index (represented by 7 segments as in calculator) turned upside-down also produces a digit.
> If no digit is produced, just add.
>
> The multiplied indexes are
> 1 (turned to 1)
> 5 (turned to 5)
> 6 (turned to 9)
> 8 turned to 8)
> 9 (turned to 6)

So the answer is

> 12, 7, 27 and 16, 36, 32

Comment: [SPOILER (hover to reveal)](/a/4651 "Another one that works. Wow. It blows me a way that the numbers provided by the randomizer work into such foreign sollutions.")

Comment: wonderfully contrived ! I like this

Answer (score 0):

If we follow the rule of

> if the index of a equation is equal to one of the numbers to be added and numbers to be added are both even or both odd, there is multiplication instead of adding.
> **EDIT**:
>  If only first of the numbers is checked against the index, the answer would differ on the last equation

So the numbers are

> **EDIT**: 35, 8, **27** or 35, 8, **12**

Comment: I would like to reply but do not know how you guys do the spoilers in these and don't want to give info that will spoil MY solution for others.

Comment: [SPOILER (hover to reveal)](/a/4651 "Here's the content of my spoiler, which you can only see by hovering over this link...")

Comment: Source for the above comment: [ SPOILER (hover to reveal)](/a/4651 "Here's the content of my spoiler, which you can only see by hovering over this link...") by Alconja (after the first "["  remove the space)

Comment: [SPOILER (hover to reveal)](/a/4651 "It is interesting that you used indexing to find valid answers that were different to mine when I also used indexing. I can say if I included more examples your indexing solution would not have worked.")

Comment: [SPOILER (hover to reveal)](/a/4651 "Astounding. Again another index based solution that gives valid answers. Even more surprising it gives MY answers but is not remotely the index based solution I used.")

Comment: remember, not to use it a lot, as hover do not work for mobile users